# All previous screens are mounted again while navigating to next ones react-navigation 5x

Tags: react-native

For example, we are on screen A of StackNavigator1, which has screens: A, B, C. When navigating to screen B, the A screen is mounted again! When you go from B to C, A and B are mounted again and so on.

As said in documentation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html),

Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.

But is doesn't work like this! All screens in the stack keep on mounting while navigating to the next one. And, besides performance concern, if you have an API call in componentDidMount() or in useEffect(() => APIcall(), []) hook, it is being called every time you navigate to a new screen and causes various bugs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,

when we wrap the navigator in another component, remounting is happening, simple place navigator on the top-level component.

Issue resolved for me